# How to view word, Power point and Excel files in browser using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to open word, Power point and excel files in browser like PDF file, we can open PDF file in browser. help...!

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. One way is to allow Google docs to open the files.

Comment: PDF works because some PDF viewer / plugin is installed on the client... IF the client has Office installed locally then it is a question of security settings to get that working.

Comment: This is browser, not PHP functionality. Most browsers have PDF and even xls, ppt viewer addins. From PHP's perspective, you just open the file. Not sure if there's a way for PHP to check if the add-in is available though, which is something you'd probably want too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be way too complicated to do from scratch. I suggest using a docs viewer https://docs.google.com/viewer which already has pretty fine file format support. It basically converts those file into html/canvas and it might be embedded.

Comment: ya I agree, but I want to create interface which will able to open and edit documents in browser.

Comment: @Madhav Open *and edit*? That's quite some scope for a project. Google has invested years into Google Docs and it's still nowhere near a full-fledged Office app. Are you sure you're aware of the scope of what you're asking about?

Comment: @deceze I am not saying I want all functionality like MS Office or Google docs, I just want to open it in browser.... display it's content.

Comment: @deceze can we use Google Docs API for opening the documents in browser....?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it.

We can view PDF files because browsers usually have a plugin to display this type of document. So, if you point your browser directly to *http://yoursite.com/your.pdf* you will see the PDF content.

It's not the same with DOC, PPT, XLS, etc. Try to point your browser to one of these files. Usually the browser asks you if you want to download the file, 'cause he isn't able to display it!

Comment: I have got one link checkout...http://www.xsolutions.at/produkte

Comment: What? I do not understand page language (German)?